# Why does Newton's iteration method for solving differential equations fail in the case of non-linear systems of equations?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system, jacobian

Suppose we have a simultaneous system of 2 black-box non-linear equations in 2 variables $\{a,b\}$:

$$ F_1(a,b) = 0$$
$$ F_2(a,b) = 0$$

**Newton's iteration method** for solving this system of equations goes as follows:

1. Starting with any initial guess, eg. $a_0=0$, $b_0=0$, we calculate

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \frac{dF_1}{da} & \frac{dF_1}{db} \\ \frac{dF_2}{da} & \frac{dF_2}{db} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_1 \\ \sigma_2 \end{bmatrix} = - \begin{bmatrix} F_1(a_0, b_0) \\ F_2(a_0, b_0) \end{bmatrix}$$

2. This $\sigma$ correction amounts can be found by inverting the left-hand-side Jacobian matrix, and adding the amounts to the original guess $a_0, b_0$:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ b_1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a_0 \\ b_0 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_1 \\ \sigma_2 \end{bmatrix} $$

and the iteration can be continued to find $a_2, b_2$ etc, converging incrementally upon the solution to the original system of equations.

However, I have heard it mentioned that this method *fails* when $F_1$ and $F_2$ are non-linear.

I not sure the exact reason why this is true for non-linear equations. In the above sequence of steps, where precisely do the non-linear $F_1$, $F_2$ break the convergence to the correct solution?

Comment: It could strongly depend on the initial guesses.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thank you. More specifically, I have tried this on the case of 10 equations in 10 unknowns in Einstein's field equations $R_{μν}−\frac{1}{2}g_{μν}R=T_{μν}$
, and repeated iteration cannot find the correct solution for the unknowns. Is this because of the non-linearity of the 10 equations?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need Newton's method to solve linear systems. Meaning that the method is constructed for non-linear systems. It would not be a famous, named method if it was a failure for its purpose.

For non-linear systems it is highly unlikely, but not entirely impossible, that you find a solution with the first step. So more commonly you have to iterate the Newton step. In fortunate cases you get eventually convergence, the function values and step sizes reducing to zero. In some neighborhood of the solution this reduction will happen from the first step on, in other cases the sequence will jump around seemingly randomly. In unfortunate cases, which will happen more often the higher the dimension of the system, there will be no convergence.

It depends on context what "the method fails" precisely means.

Comment: I meant by "the method fails" literally, as in the final iterated values for $a, b$ don't result in $F_1, F_2$ being zero at all, no matter how long we perform the iteration. More specifically, I have tried this on the case of 10 equations in 10 unknowns in Einstein's field equations $R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2} g_{\mu\nu}R = T_{\mu\nu}$, and the iteration cannot find the correct solution for the unknowns. Do you know the reason why this is so?

Comment: $g$ and $R$ are coupled via differential equations, which is a sharp step-up from non-linear but "algebraic" (here: without differentiation) equations. Otherwise, dimension 10 is large enough that the basins of quadratic convergence are rather small, so random initial points will seldom lead to convergence. Use globalization methods such as homotopy or path-following (also no guarantee for convergence, but higher probability).